# Refactoring observer pattern interface

Tags: c++, c++14

I have a observer pattern implemented and I'm using two base classes called `Subject` and `Observer`. - The `Subject` class is an abstract class that has methods to insert the observers. And the `Observer` is just an interface.

What I want is to provide a safer interface to classes that inherit to access the vector of observers and that is the way I implemented...

What would you do to make this better? Is this a bad design? Anything wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class Observer
{
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}

    virtual void notifyHuman() = 0;
    virtual void notifyRobot() = 0;
};

class Subject
{
    typedef std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Observer>> vector_type;
public:
    virtual ~Subject() {}

    void attachObserver(vector_type::value_type observer)
    {
        container.push_back(std::move(observer));
    }

    vector_type::const_iterator begin() const
    {
        return container.begin();
    }

    vector_type::const_iterator end() const
    {
        return container.end();
    }

    virtual void notifyHuman() = 0;
    virtual void notifyRobot() = 0;
private:
    vector_type container;
};

class FooSubject : public Subject
{
public:
    FooSubject() {}
    ~FooSubject() {}

    void notifyHuman()
    {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [] (auto & observer) {
            observer->notifyHuman();
        });
    }

    void notifyRobot()
    {
        std::for_each(begin(), end(), [] (auto & observer) {
            observer->notifyRobot();
        });
    }
};

class BarObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    BarObserver() {}
    ~BarObserver() {}

    void notifyHuman()
    {
        std::cout << "received notification of human." << std::endl;
    }

    void notifyRobot()
    {
        std::cout << "received notification of robot." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FooSubject subject;
    subject.attachObserver(std::make_unique<BarObserver>());
    subject.notifyHuman();
    subject.notifyRobot();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks good.

This is a little confusing:

```
void attachObserver(vector_type::value_type observer)
```

To see what I have to pass to this function. I need to look up `vector_type` (which is in the class). I would make it more explicit so that I can see exactly what is expected:

```
void attachObserver(std::unique_ptr<Oberver> observer)
```

Don't see the need for:

```
class FooSubject : public Subject
```

I would just put all methods in `Subject` (no need for a `FoodSubject`). But this is a pattern not a design and you may have a reason that are not obvious from the current question.

There is no need to define methods that are covered by the default versions.

```
// I would not bother with this
FooSubject() {}
~FooSubject() {}
```

Comment: Thanks Loki - I made `FooSubject` because I may want to create others subjects after... then `Subject` is just a type. Open/Closed principle - "should be open for extension, but closed for modification" - right? - And the `vector_type` I made most because of the return of `begin` and `end` - What to do if I remove? Use `auto` instead? (C++14)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest changing the interface of `Observer` just a bit.

```
class Subject;

class Observer
{
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}

    virtual void notifyHuman(Subject& subject) = 0;
    virtual void notifyRobot(Subject& subject) = 0;
};
```

This provides some context to the concrete sub-types of `Observer`. Depending on the type of the `Subject` and the state of the object, an observer may do different things. For example, `BarObserver` might have been designed to deal only with `BarSubjects`.

```
class BarObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    BarObserver() {}
    ~BarObserver() {}

    void notifyHuman(Subject& subject)
    {
        BarSubject* barSubject = dynamic_cast<BarSubject*>(&subject);
        if ( barSubject )
        {
            std::cout << "received notification of human on a BarSubject." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void notifyRobot(Subject& subject)
    {
        BarSubject* barSubject = dynamic_cast<BarSubject*>(&subject);
        if ( barSubject )
        {
            std::cout << "received notification of robot on a BarSubject." << std::endl;
        }
    }
};
```

The implementations of `notifyHuman` and `notifyRobot` in the `Subject` hierarchy have to be updated to pass `*this` to the observers.

```
void notifyHuman()
{
    std::for_each(begin(), end(), [] (auto & observer) {
        observer->notifyHuman(*this);
    });
}

void notifyRobot()
{
    std::for_each(begin(), end(), [] (auto & observer) {
        observer->notifyRobot(*this);
    });
}
```

Comment: I really liked your modifications, thank you very much.

Comment: Though I also like the modification. It only becomes useful if an Observer can be attached to multiple Subjects simultaneously. With Subject taking ownership of the observer that is not the case and suggests we should modify the interface even further by using a non owning Subject.